# How to write spring XML configuration without copy paste from internet

Tags: spring

I have just started writing spring application and I want to admit that write now I am copy pasting the below xml lines either from internet or from my previous applications. I want to know that is there any way to write all these lines from some spring jars or any way other than copy pasting from internet or any file like in my case.

For Example for writing spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml, we all need these below lines at the top of our xml.

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

For example for a hibernate-cfg.xml, we need these at the top of our xml

Please also tell me if there is any automatic way of generating these lines or I can refer these in some spring jar documentation.

Comment: This is a valid question because everyone seems to be pasting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the XML schema definitions in a valid XML if you are using types defined in one or more of those XML schemas. In case of Spring, in order for Spring to work its magic, the spring specific XMLs need to be configured correctly. If you are configuring Spring specific XMLs (like application-context.xml or dispatch servlet xml), you are most likely be using complex types defined in those Spring schemas. So in other words, you have to specify each schema at the top of your xml. How you do that is up to you. You can copy-paste those xsd declaration or you can make a template of all these XMLs and then start building your XMLs based on your project needs. Personally, I don't see any challenges whatsoever in copying and pasting these xsd declarations.